# NodeJs express MongoDB with jest error while executing test case

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jasmine, jestjs

**Previous Question Link

[Open Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50075889/jest-tests-are-running-beforeall)**

**Scenario**

I've trying to test if my route for GET endpoint work or not which I've set correctly and I've tested by running server. But my test case gives me following error

```
Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
```

I've searched a bit and have tried all possible solutions which are stated but it still gives me same error.

**Code**

```
const request = require ('supertest');
const app = require ('../../app');
const db = require ('../../db.js');
const url = process.env.MONGO_URI || 'mongodb://localhost:27017'

beforeAll (done => {
  db.connect (url, err => {
    if (err) {
      console.log ('Unable to connect', err);
      process.exit (1);
    }else{
        console.log('Succesfully connected')
    }
  });
});

afterAll (done => {
  db.close ();
});


test ('should response the GET method',done => {
    const res = request (app).get ('/expense');
    return res
      .then (json => {
        console.log ("Length",json.body.length);
        expect (json.body.length).toBe (1, done ());
      })
      .catch (err => {});
  },10000);
```

**Test Output**

```
 ● Console

    console.log test/express/startupTest.test.js:12
      Succesfully connected
    console.log test/express/startupTest.test.js:26
      Length 1

  ● should response the GET method

    Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.

      at pTimeout (node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:53:21)
      at Timeout.callback [as _onTimeout] (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/Window.js:523:19)
      at ontimeout (timers.js:469:11)
      at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:304:5)
      at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:264:5)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 2 passed, 3 total
Tests:       1 failed, 6 passed, 7 total
Snapshots:   1 passed, 1 total
Time:        6.58s
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to invoke `done` callback after establishing connection with the DB.

```
beforeAll (done => {
  db.connect (url, err => {
    if (err) {
      console.log ('Unable to connect', err);
      process.exit (1);
    }else{
      console.log('Succesfully connected');
      done();
    }
  });
});
```

Same with `afterAll`:

```
afterAll (done => {
  db.close (() => done());
});
```

Also, you don't need to use `done` callback in test case, since you are returning a promise:

```
test ('should response the GET method', () => {
  const res = request (app).get ('/expense');
  return res
    .then (json => {
      console.log ("Length",json.body.length);
      expect (json.body.length).toBe (1);
    })
    .catch (err => {});
});
```

When you return a promise from a test case, test resolution will be delayed until the promise resolves.

Comment: Thank you it solved my problem, I thought the test case I wrote is giving me problem so I was using done in the test case. Damn these errors are sometimes misleading. Thank you again.